# How to Update Order Attribute

Tags: attributes, orders, module, sales-order

I was able to successfully add new order field through an install script:

```
$installer->addAttribute('order', 'is_local', array('type'=>Varien_Db_Ddl_Table::TYPE_SMALLINT, 'default'=>1));
```

However, I could not update the "default" property of it, let's say default=>0. One suggested to use updateAttribute() https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10420199/magento-module-setup-change-product-attribute-to-not-required but it doesn't work in order table.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Hi you  can do this by  `updateAttribute`() function

Create `upgrade installer` and  on the upgrade file update field  by updateAttribute() function.

Here

```
$installer = $this;
/* @var $installer Mage_Sales_Model_Mysql4_Setup */

$installer->startSetup();
$installer->updateAttribute('order', 'is_local',  array('default'=>0));
$installer->endSetup();
```

**format:**

```
$params=array()
$installer->updateAttribute(EntityTypeId,attribute_code',$params );
```

Till now ,i cannot find the where the issue But currently, i give u an alternative solution:

```
$installer = $this;
/* @var $installer Mage_Sales_Model_Mysql4_Setup */

$installer->startSetup();
$installer->run("ALTER TABLE  {$this->getTable('sales_flat_order')} CHANGE `is_local` `is_local` SMALLINT(6) NULL DEFAULT '0' COMMENT 'Is Local'");
$installer->endSetup();
```

Comment: I am not sure but I already did that, both: $installer->updateAttribute('order', 'is_local', array('default'=>0)); and $installer->updateAttribute('order', 'is_local', 'default', 0);

Comment: And both didn't update the order attribute.

Comment: ok, i am checking

Comment: Getting back, I did a similar approach, and yes this works. Just  a note on $this->getTable('sales_flat_order') which could be $installer->getTable('sales/order').

Answer (score 0):

Here's what I did, since sales/order is a flat table:

```
$installer->run("
ALTER TABLE `{$installer->getTable('sales/order')}` CHANGE `is_local` `is_local` SMALLINT(6) NULL DEFAULT '0' COMMENT 'Is Local';
");
```

and

```
$installer->updateAttribute('order', 'is_local', 'default_value', 0);
```

to make it backward compatible.

And verified the default value of the field/attribute is now 0.

Complete:

```
$installer = $this;
/* @var $installer Mage_Sales_Model_Mysql4_Setup */

$installer->startSetup();

$installer->updateAttribute('order', 'is_local', 'default_value', 0); 
$installer->run("ALTER TABLE `{$installer->getTable('sales/order')}` CHANGE `is_local` `is_local` SMALLINT(6) NULL DEFAULT '0' COMMENT 'Is Local';");

$installer->endSetup();
```